# How to hide row of a multiple column based on hided data values

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to hide data of column NAME by some value of XXXX for which i want to hide the other two column like the NAME column data have some values of XXXX for which i want to hide the data of Address and Number

```
    data = [['NISAMANEE ROWELL', '9198762345','qwerpoiuytr','98 Oxford Ave.Elk Grove Village, IL 60007'], ['ALICE BAISDEN', '8756342865','asdfghjklxc', '94 Valley Rd.Miami Gardens, FL 33056'], ['MARC COGNETTI', '9198762345', 'qwerasdfzxcv' , '221 Summer CircleGreer, SC 29650'], ['JOHNS HOPKINS HEALTHCARE', '9654987642','asdfghjkl', '8522 Pendergast AvenueVilla Park, IL 60181'], ['AMANDA PELLETIER', '9654987642','acderfgds', '8522 Pendergast AvenueVilla Park, IL 60181']] 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Number','Information','Address']) 
    df
def name(x):
    x=x.title()                              # title the string
    res=pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))            #tokenizing 
    arr_Val=[]                               # storing each word in this array
    #exceptionList=['Healthcare','Lerner']    # exception list .. MUST UPDATE HERE !!!!
    exc_list=['Mackesson Inc','Care','Healthcare','Henery Schien','Besse','LLC','CandP','INC','LTD','PHARMACY','PHARMACEUTICAL','HOSPITAL','COMPANY','ELECTRONICS','APP','VOLUNTEERS','SPECIALITIES','APPLIANCE','EXPRESS','MAGAZINE','SUPPLY','ENDOSCOPY','NETWandK','SCHOOL','AT&T','SOLUTIONS','SANITATION','SYSTEMS','COMPOUNDING','CLINIC','UTILITIES','DEPARTMENT','CREATIVE','PIN','employment','consultant','units','label','machine','anesthesia','services','medical','community','plaza','tech','bipolar','brand','commerce','testing','inspection','killer','plus','electric','division','diagnostic','materials','imaging','international','district','chamber','city','products','essentials','life','scissand','leasing','units','health','healthcare','surgical','enterprises','print','radiology','water','screens','telecom','neurology','biologicals','laundry','owners','law','offices','pharm','office','fire','safety','family','instruments','publishing','automation','center','plate','group','mall','diabetes','estate','electronic','fire','coffee','water','café','factandy','society','group','precision','oxygen','pizza','mills','lock','exterminate','fresh','graves','emeregency','care','security','empire','chemical','associate','mind','optics','coland','toolbox','properties','contract','agreement','learning','exchange','plumbing','leica','sales','shoppe','league','institute','thermo','gas','print','shack','manufacturing','colgate','environmental','neuro','state','board','children','journal','phone','USA','paper','urgent','radio','day','admin','level','bag','church','coast','account','financial','candpandation','sales','andthopedics','andtho','control','handler','king','test','filter','nandth','south','east','west','refrige','laband','bank','system','scientific','instrument','capital','pfizer','lab','labanda','alcon','group','vision','care','alarm','endo','stryke','realty','pest','optic','renewal','star','surgery','stuff','notes','tables','ssurgical','plasma','plaster','code','construction','notes','ink','park','power','gear','link','recandds','amazon','sweet','fish','food','sign','farm','concept','guard','county','prod','duplex','dental','safe','tax','shop','american','ameri','wandks','cloud','exam','therapy','optical','insurance','depot','doctands','telephone','distibutands','cable','comcast','image','first','choice','wear','energy','duke','nandthside','transcription','engineers','alarm','deli','universal','shield','cleaning','resources','int','direct','out','steak','americas','bread','panera','design','media','eye','kreme','krispy','verizon','one','procare','access','point','shield','total','display','pepsi','cola','distributand','consulting','cleaners','flags','mutual','comp','premier','pedaitrics','.com','enterprise','café','linen','opthalmic','upholstery','card','business','waste','innovations','architectural','agency','photography','exterminatands','times','global','house','ultrasound','aetna','flandist','scripture','steel','fast','vascular','corp','town','partnership','utility','advanced','disposal','bcbs','village','payments','corporation','benefit','service','court','dept','partnership','height','coporation','national','grid','fedex','xerox','walgreen','united','walmart','pse&g','communication','reliant','cross','cigna','terminix','staffing','office','admin','phone','expert','source','management','cash','plumber','springs','communications','expert','berkshire','staples','highmark','berkshire','of','Network','window','Locum','Delta','Greater','Treasurer','Investment','Elite','Explore','Foundation','Rentals','Rental','Textile','Municipal','Authority','Treat','Development','University','ACCRUENT','ROTO-ROOTER','KPMG','LLP','Fertilizing','Roofing','Central','Collection','UNIT','Aviation','Development','Acquisition','Square','Unlimited','light','bulbs','CO.','Doctors','Exterminators','Public','Utilities','Registration','Attorney']
    exceptionList = [x.title() for x in exc_list]

    for i in range( len (res)):              # looping to store tokenized words into array
        if( res[i][0] in exceptionList ):
            return x
        else:
            arr_Val.append(res[i][0])
            #print(res)

    for i in range( len(res) ):             # checking the POS as proper Noun (NNP)
        if( res[i][1]=='NNP'):
            length=len(res[i][0])
            arr_Val[i]=str(length*'X' )
    return(' '.join(arr_Val)) 

df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype(str).apply(name)
```

I want to hide the rows of two column Address and Number for which the the name column has contain  XXXXX  the column Address and Number data should also be hided by the XXXXX of any length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of this problem is the masking of all maskable columns for rows that fit some requirement.  Supposing that I had a boolean series that told me which rows to mask (call it `mask`), I could use `pandas.DataFrame.where` to mask out where my `mask` is `False`.  You can also pass a parameter to supply alternatives.

In this case, we are passing a `pandas.Series` with aligns with the `DataFrame`'s `index`.

The rest of the functions are components to calculate OP's desired conditions.

---

```
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize

def get_tags(x):
    """Should be obvious"""
    return pos_tag(word_tokenize(x.title()))

def is_proper(y):
    """Check second element equal to 'NNP'"""
    return y[1] == 'NNP'

def has_proper(tags):
    """Check all tags to see if any are 'NNP'"""
    return any(map(is_proper, tags))
```

---

```
def get_exceptions_checker(exc_list):
    """Return a function that checks for membership in the
    exceptions list.  I want to clean this up so we use `set`
    containment and process it once."""
    exceptions = set(map(str.title, exc_list))
    return lambda x: x[0] in exceptions

def has_exception(tags, checker):
    """Check if any tags has an exception"""
    return any(map(checker, tags))

def should_hide(x, checker):
    """Combine `proper` and `exception` checks.
    Essentially, this keeps the creation of tags to a minimum."""
    tags = get_tags(x.title())
    proper = has_proper(tags)
    exception = has_exception(tags, checker)
    return proper and not exception

def hider(x):
    """Defines what to replace with.
    Feel free to play with this to define other ways."""
    return 'X' * len(str(x))
```

---

```
# `is_exception` is the function that you pass `x` to and
# it will tell you if `x` is an exception
is_exception = get_exceptions_checker(['Mackesson Inc', 'Care', 'Healthcare'])

# define all the columns you want to hide if the condition is satisfied
cols_to_hide = ['Name', 'Number', 'Address']

# Boolean values specifying which rows to hide
mask = df.Name.apply(should_hide, checker=is_exception)
```

---

```
#             Subsetted df   Hide Everything   but only keep rows
#                                              where mask is `True`
#             ____________     __________      ___________
#           /              \ /            \  /             \
df.assign(**df[cols_to_hide].applymap(hider).where(mask, df))

                       Name      Number   Information                                     Address
0          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXX   qwerpoiuytr   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1             XXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXX   asdfghjklxc        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2             XXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXX  qwerasdfzxcv            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
3  JOHNS HOPKINS HEALTHCARE  9654987642     asdfghjkl  8522 Pendergast AvenueVilla Park, IL 60181
4          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXX     acderfgds  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ,can you please explain your code ,it will be helpful for me

Comment: I will. I had to step away from my desk

Comment: I would just say the 'hider' function should return a Xs of the same length no matter the underlying data to properly mask.

Comment: Thankyou so much @piRSquared it would be so helpful

Comment: @PURU let me know if that helps.

Comment: hi @piRSquared it helps a lot but i had a doubt how( return proper and not exception ) as it return false and true i didn't understand this line and what is the role def is_proper(y)